# MVC 5 Application / Photo uploads work fine on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, mobile

I have a MVC application that has a Product model and multiple child images in an Image entity, which are uploaded to Azure Blob Storage. This all works great on desktop but will not work with a mobile browser. Just straight MVC, no Web API.

Any ideas why the mobile browsers won't pass the selected image to the controller?

I repeat: this works fine on a desktop with just about any browser... just not mobile.

Model:

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageGuid { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Image Title")]
    public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Image File")]
    public byte[] ImageFile { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product product { get; set; }
}
```

View (Create):

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,ImageGuid,ImageUrl,ProductId,ImageTitle,ImageFile")] Image image, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

//Yes... I know this might not be the best place for this block...
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength != 0)
            {
                string guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                image.ImageGuid = guid;
                CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = GetBlobContainer();


                //Get reference to the picture blob or create if not exists. 
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(guid);

                //Save to storage
                blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.InputStream);


                image.ImageUrl = blobContainer.Uri + "/" + image.ImageGuid;
            }            

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Images.Add(image);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Products", new { id = image.ProductId });
        }

        ViewBag.ProductId = new SelectList(db.Products, "Id", "ProductName", image.ProductId);
        return View(image);
    }
```

Comment: More details, what desktop browsers did you try in and what mobile browser did you try in and what did and did not work?

Comment: I tried Chrome and Puffin browsers on my Android. Both allow me to select an image, hit submit, and it tries to send an empty image to Azure Blob Storage. If I had to guess, I don't think the image is actually getting sent to the controller from the view. Difficult to troubleshoot on from my phone though.

Comment: I think I figured it out... either the file size or the file name was too big on the photos I was trying to upload. Grabbed a small image and it worked like a charm on Chrome on my phone.

Comment: <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="10240" />
  </system.web>     fixed it for me.

Comment: Another problem was that blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.InputStream); was behaving badly for larger files. Changed UploadFromStreamAsync to UploadFromStream and all problems disappeared.